# Finding the index of a ComboBoxItem in a WPF Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I added a `SelectionChanged` event to my ComboBox, and I need to find the index of the previous selected item. I can't find a simple way to find the item index, though. I've got:

```
// In the XAML file
<ComboBox Name="myCombobox" ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollectionView}" SelectionChanged="myCombobox_SelectionChanged" />


// In the XAML.cs file
public void myCombobox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem item = e.RemovedItems[0];
    if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ComboBoxItem item = e.RemovedItems[0];
        if (item != null)
            int index = /* Find index of this item! */;
    }
}
```

What is the easiest way to retrieve the correct index here? Why doesn't the `ComboBoxItem` just have an `Index` property?

Comment: your itemssource is some list?

Comment: Indeed it is. I updated the question slightly to make that explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try something like this:

```
Combobox comboBox = sender as ComboBox;

 if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ComboBoxItem item = e.RemovedItems[0];
        if (item != null)
            int index = combobox.Items.IndexOf(item);
    }
```

Comment: Ah, that works! I was looking in the `ComboBox` class for an `indexOf()`, and I didn't realise it was in the `ComboBox.Items`.